# mathematica, SequenceAlignment, defining SimilarityRules

Tags: alignment, expression, wolfram-mathematica, sequence

I have a question about Mathematica's SimilarityRules defining (for e.g. SequenceAlignment function). So help centre clearly stands for

"SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, b_} -> -1}, giving a score of +1 for any pair of identical elements, and a score of -1 for any mismatch, deletion or insertion."

Ok, I get it, but what if I want to give different score for mismatch, and different for indeles? I tried:

SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 3, {{a_, b_} && {{a_!=""} && {b_ != ""}}} -> -8} and many other combination of {}, && positions, but it doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions, is it just a typo I'm doing, or it's rather a silly idea to define it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit.. sorry about answering too quickly: SequenceAlignment does not seem to work with such conditionals..  I'd sugest you ask over on mathematica.stackexchange.com.  I'd also sugest you provide an example of input and expected output to clarify what you are trying to acomplish.

your question really is about pattern testing .. here are two ways to do what you want with patterns..

```
{{"A", "A"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A", ""}} /. {
         {a_, b_} /; a == b -> 1,
         {a_, b_} /; (a != b && b != "" && a != "") -> -8,
         {a_, b_} /; (a != b ) -> -1
   }

{{"A", "A"}, {"A", "B"}, {"A",  ""}} /. {
   {_, _}?((#[[1]] == #[[2]]) &) -> 1,
   {_, _ }?((#[[1]] != #[[2]] && #[[1]] != "" && #[[2]] !=  "") &) -> -8,
   {_, _}?((#[[1]] != #[[2]]) &) -> -1
      }
```

These are doing the same thing and produce {1,-8,-1} basically with slightly differenct syntax, see `Pattern Test` and `Condition` in the manual.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer I'm digging in mathematica stackexchange now. 

All I need is to use normally SequenceAlignment, but with different scores for indeles, and different for mismatches, the output will be just normal alignment, but depending on the scores, for two strings alignment will be different :)

Comment: Have a look at /;
This is the perfect answer I got at mathematica stack:

For instance: SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 3, {a_ /; a != "", b_ /; b != ""} -> -8}
works perfectly!